# How to disable a tab bar item?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to hide or disable a tab bar item on a tab bar throughout the entire app for a certain use case?

Example:
While the user is logged in, and they do not have a Role of 'manager', the last tab bar item will be hidden throughout the app. When they log in again as a manager the last tab bar will be enabled and not hidden.

Comment: Seems like it would be better design to just not show the last tab at all if the user is not a manager.

Answer (score 3):

If you are inside the source file of the UITabBarController, just add below code in viewDidLoad method to disable last item

Also below code assumes you are having UITabBarItem items in tab bar. Otherwise you know what type of item is it so you can cast accordingly

```
if let items = tabBar.items as? [UITabBarItem] {
  if items.count > 0 {
    let itemToDisable = items[items.count - 1]
    itemToDisable.enabled = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better code (in Swift 4):

```
tabBar.items?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution (in Swift 5)

```
tabBarControlled?.tabBar.items?[2].isEnabled = isManager
```

Comment: Where 2 is the index of the tab in the tabBarController

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 one liner

```
let n = 2.   //The tab number to disable
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![n].isEnabled = false
```